# Why do I get negative values in my array?

Tags: arrays, numpy, integer

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1, 4, 2, 7])
C = np.array([3, 2, 5, 1])

K = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000])

K[A] *= K[A]
print(K)
K[C] *= K[C]
print(K)
K[A] *= K[C]
print(K)
```

And it returns:

```
[   100  40000  90000    400 250000    600    700 640000    900   1000]
[       100 1600000000 -489934592     160000     250000     360000   700     640000        900       1000]
[        100 -1525678080   673857536      160000   229347328      36000 700 -1807745024         900        1000]
```